# listView with textBox in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to create a listView. Every row of the list contains textView and EditText  .How to make it?Thanks in advance !!

Note: I need to design this by using java only(Without using xml)

Comment: Are you doing a form? If so just use a `LinearLayout` inside an `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a layout for a list row containing your edit box and text view. Then make sure your adapter inflates it correctly and you're set to go.

There are a lot of good tutorials around. For example here:
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/